# Problem with Joomla auto logoff feature

Tags: joomla1.5

I am using joomla 1.5.14(Stable),PHP Version: 5.2.6,Web Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS), CBSub: 1.2.1.
My login is with cbsub, I have added an IP check for user in login function in comprofiler.php. As I added my code for check, auto log off feature of Joomla is not working properly. Can anyone suggest how can I enable auto log off feature without deleting my IP check.

Thanks in advance!!

Gurpreet Kaur

Answer (score 2):

Just change the session time in Global Configuration.